# how to expand dropdown with more sub tabs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/L4r3j/

I have a working jQuery drop down that will eventually redirect to all the pages i create. However, i would like to expand upon this, and have a list pop out of the hovered item(preferably to the side) to show more option on that sub heading. So, once the first subject is hovered over the drop down will expand, then once a subject is hovered over in the dropdown, a menu with expand to the side with more options.

Heres my current code:

HTML:

```
<div class="nav">
    <ul class="navigation">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Galaxy S4</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Verizon</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">ATT</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sprint</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">T-Mobile</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">International</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () 
{
    $('.navigation li').hover(
        function () 
        {
            $('ul', this).fadeIn(); 
        },
        function () 
        {
            $('ul', this).fadeOut(); 
        });
});
```

Comment: Anyone or any suggestions?

Comment: There are countless jQuery menus available. Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: @LeeTaylor because I would like to use the code I already have, as well as make it a sort of a learning expirence

Comment: OK, so explain what the issues are (rather than explaining what you want). Also, add your code to a jsfiddle, this will help people see what you have done.

Comment: @LeeTaylor There isn't really a problem other than I don't know how to do what im asking, and I'll do this right now

Comment: @leeTaylor added the jsfiddle ; http://jsfiddle.net/L4r3j/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would rather have something that affects just the sub menus, my approach would be to give the sub menu a class name, and then have the `hover` event binding only on that but enact the changes on the child `sub-menu`.

I gave each main menu item a `menu-item` class attribute and a `sub-menu` to the children without too much alteration of your javascript, just on the selectors that you are using to get the elements to bind your events to.

Our basic structure:

```
Menu:
   1. Item 1 (no sub-menu)
   2. Item 2 (has a sub-menu)
       a. sub-menu item 1 (no sub-menu)
       b. sub-menu item 2 (has a sub-menu)
           i. sub-sub-menu item 1
          ii. sub-sub-menu item 2
   3. Item 3 (has a sub-menu)
       a. sub-menu item 1 (no sub-menu)
       b. sub-menu item 2 (has a sub-menu)
```

`HTML` (Simplified)

```
<ul id="top-level-menu">
    <li class='menu-item'>
        No Sub Menu
    </li>
    <li class='menu-item'>
        Nested Sub Menu
        <ul class='sub-menu'>
            <li class='menu-item'>
                Nested Menu
                <ul class='sub-menu'>
                    <li>
                        Nested
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        Sub
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        Menu
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                no nested list
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class='menu-item'>
        Regular Sub menu
        <ul class='sub-menu'>
            <li>
                Sub item 1
            </li>
            <li>
                Sub item 2
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The `CSS` portions exists just to hide the `.sub-menu`s on initialization, and style for showing them on the right of the element, the latter of which could be set up however you wish.

`CSS`

```
.sub-menu {
    display: none;
}
/* optional and replaceable with similar logic for display */
.show-sub-menu-on-right {
    position: absolute;
    left: 100% !important; /* make sure to override inherited positioning*/
    top: 0%;
}
```

Now for the `jQuery` we just need to apply the bindings to the correct elements.  We want the `li.menu-item` to show their children of class `sub-menu`, so we set up our function to do just that.

`javascript/jQuery`

```
$('.menu-item').hover(
    function() {
        var subMenu = $(this).children('.sub-menu');
        $(subMenu).fadeIn()
    },
    function() {
        var subMenu = $(this).children('.sub-menu');
        $(subMenu).fadeOut();
    }
)
```

I believe this is what you're after?

Below is the above logic applied to your case.

**EDIT:**
Here is the jsfiddle, modded from the one you provided, which shows what you want, I also added one `CSS` class `.show-sub-menu-on-right` just for visual effect.

[even more updated jsfiddle with all the fixings](http://jsfiddle.net/6dApS/3/)

**EDIT 2**

[Example with sub-sub-menus](http://jsfiddle.net/uvm75/) and how it can apply to nested menus.

**EDIT 3**

[Example with slide out and down menus](http://jsfiddle.net/47R3C/1/)

The real code that i added is in the javascript, I moved put it here for reference.  The main thing is to switch all the `.menu-item` that are children of a submenu to `sub-menu-item`

Basically the logic is similar.  The same as before, we just declare a class `.sub-menu-item` and give these elements different bindings for `hover` behavior.  We want to get all the children `li`, then we assert a few things on the list because now the animation is in our hands.

```
$('.sub-menu-item').hover(
    // When mouse enters the .navigation element
    function () {
        //Fade in the navigation submenu
        var subMenu = $(this).children('.sub-menu'); // Get the sub menu
        if (!subMenu) {
            return; // if it doesn't have a sub menu quit
        }
        var subMenuItems = $(subMenu).children('li'); // get all the sub menu items

        // Get the max width we need to expand the menu to
        var maxWidth = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < subMenuItems.length; i++) {
            if ( maxWidth < $(subMenuItems[i]).width() ) {
                maxWidth = $(subMenuItems[i]).width();
            }
        }

        var firstItem = $(subMenuItems).first(); // get the first item
        var restOfItems = subMenuItems.slice(1); // slice of the rest.
        $(firstItem).width(0); // make sure the element has width 0 so we can animate it                   
        $(subMenu).show();  // make the submenu ul itself is visible
        $(subMenuItems).each(function () {  // Make sure all the items in the ul
            $(this).css('display', 'none'); // are not yet visible
        });
        $(firstItem).show();  // make the first item visible
        $(firstItem).animate({   // animate the first item growing
            width:maxWidth+"px",
        },function() { // function to execute after animation is complete
            $(restOfItems).slideDown();  // slide down the rest of the list
        });
    },
    // When mouse leaves the .navigation element
    function () {
        //Fade out the navigation submenu
        var subMenu = $(this).children('.sub-menu');

        $(subMenu).fadeOut(); // fadeOut will hide the sub cat menu
    }
);
```

If you are looking for a generic way to handle this you here is a skeleton:

HTML

```
<ul class='menu'>
    <li class='menu-item-with-animation-style-1'>
        <ul class='sub-menu'>
            <li class='menu-item-with-animation-style-1'>
                <ul class='sub-menu'>
                    <li class='menu-item-with-animation-style-1'>A</li>
                    <li class='menu-item-with-animation-style-4'>B</li>
                    <li class='menu-item-with-animation-style-7'>C</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class='menu-item-with-animation-style-4'>B</li>
            <li class='menu-item-with-animation-style-7'>C</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class='menu-item-with-animation-style-2'>
        <ul class='sub-menu'>
            <li class='menu-item-with-animation-style-1'>
                <ul>
                    <li>AA</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class='menu-item-with-animation-style-1'>B</li>
            <li class='menu-item-with-animation-style-1'>C</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class='menu-item-with-animation-style-3'>
        <ul class='sub-menu'>
            <li>A</li>
            <li>B</li>
            <li>C</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

javascript:

```
$('.menu-item-with-animation-style-1').hover(
     fadeInFunctionforStyle1,
     fadeOutFunctionforStyle1,    
);

$('.menu-item-with-animation-style-2').hover(
     fadeInFunctionforStyle2,
     fadeOutFunctionforStyle2,    
);

$('.menu-item-with-animation-style-1').hover(
     fadeInFunctionforStyle1,
     fadeOutFunctionforStyle1,    
);

// ....

$('.menu-item-with-animation-style-N').hover(
     fadeInFunctionforStyleN,
     fadeOutFunctionforStyleN,    
);
```

See the last menu item ("International") in the "Mixed Bag" drop down for an [Example of even more extendability](http://jsfiddle.net/47R3C/3/)

Comment: Can you update the HTML with an extra sub menu to demonstrate what youre saying please?

Comment: @sirnomnomz sure! Give me one second, i'll notify you with another comment.

Comment: @sirnomnomz check it out now!

Comment: @sirnomnomz No problem!  Was there some part of your question I could expand upon?

Comment: Wait, so the right sub menu is actually placed with the css correct? because they were given the submenu and the right showing submenu class correct? My JQuery is very very very rusty :P @farmerjoe

Comment: @sirnomnomz Yes, the `css` class handles making the sub-menu appear on the right, this of course could be handled in a multitude of ways, i.e. if you wanted it to show on the left sometimes, and sometimes right, I could give you some pointers on that if you'd like.  I went with the `css` just to focus on the display of the sub menus.  The `jQuery` handles assigning the binding of the `hover` event handlers.  It basically says for each `.menu-item` when it is hovered over, if it has a direct child of class `.sub-menu` that it should show it on entering and hide when leaving the `hover` event.

Comment: @sirnomnomz so essentially now, you would be able to add anything of class `sub-menu` as a child to anything of class `menu-item` and it would show a sub menu, you could even cascade them [as much as you want](http://jsfiddle.net/uvm75/) (Try hovering over each sub-menu item.  Now as you can see this can be done without any further `jQuery` and just by classifying the items.

Comment: @sirnomnomz Hey, I added some step-by-step logic about how I set up the jsfiddle in regards to my last two comments, let me know if anything is unclear.

Comment: how would i make the second set of sub menus slide in rather fade?

Comment: @sirnomnomz too much to add in a comment, i'll stick in an edit and let you know what i post it.

Comment: I figured out the slide in from top, but i want the sub-sub (grammar ftw) to slide in from the first sub on the right, THEN drop down

Comment: I basically want the menus coming out of the original drop down to slide out from the left menu, then slide down @farmerjoe

Comment: @sirnomnomz Do you mean sliding out the first item of the sub-sub menu, and then dropping out the rest?

Comment: you hover over the original menu up top, you hover onto one of the menus that SLIDEDOWN (i was able to figure this out) then once you hover over it, the menu that comes out of that will slide out from the left to right as a single row, THEN slide down revealing the rest of the options

Comment: @sirnomnomz gotcha, gimme a few minutes ill have a mock up

Comment: @sirnomnomz also see the very end of my answer, go to "Mixed Bag > International" to see a fun variation.

Comment: @sirnomnomz No offense intended but I am confused why you didn't award my answer with the bounty on your question, could you explain?

Comment: I'm so sorry i must have accidentally awarded it to the wrong person! Thats my bad im so sorry.

Comment: @sirnomnomz No problem, I was just so surprised because i felt we had such a good thing going haha

Comment: we definitely did, if you catch any of my questions in the future ill be sure to make sure to award you :P

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

This is the markup

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Nav 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Nav 2</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#">Nav 3</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Nav 3.1</a></li>
                ...
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#">Nav 3.4</a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Nav 3.4.1</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#">Nav 3.4.2</a>
                            <ul class="sub-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Nav 3.4.2.1</a></li>
                                ...
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        ...
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Nav 3.5</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        ...
    </ul>
</nav>
```

This is the JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( '.dropdown' ).hover(
        function(){
            $(this).children('.sub-menu').slideDown(200);
        },
        function(){
            $(this).children('.sub-menu').slideUp(200);
        }
    );
}); // end ready
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with self-promotion. However, providing link-only answers is not ideal since your web site may change and that link may become broken. Therefore, it's better to put the gist of what your link says here.